# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, postgresql, ubuntu, docker, asp.net-core-1.0

I have created WebAPI project in ASP.NET Core with targeted framework dnxcore50. There are four projects in my solution.

- WebAPI - Contains API methods
- Core - Contains IRepository, IDataContext interfaces and base classes to communicate with Postgresql with dapper
- DataAccess - Contains Repository classes for domain
- Domain - Contains domain models

My application is using `Postgresql` database to store the data and at application side I used `dapper` and `npgsql` nuget package for database operation with `Postgresql`.

Everything was worked in windows environment and after that I tried in Ubuntu 14.04 and faced 'Timeout issue' while performing `select` query in `npgsql` but I resolved that by using the solution mentioned in [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4631)  and after that everything worked perfectly in Ubuntu machine also.

So, I thought lets try to run WebAPI in docker and for that I created docker image also and successfully able to run also but unfortunately I am getting some new (compare to ubuntu 14.04) error when I call select API method which call domain repository to select data from Postgrespl by using `dapper` and `npgsql`.

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel[13]
      An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

      File name: 'System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load the specified file.
      File name: 'System.Net.Security'
         at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyName)
         at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Resolve(IntPtr gchManagedAssemblyLoadContext, AssemblyName assemblyName)
         at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
         at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
         at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open()
         at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.GetPooledConnector(NpgsqlConnection Connection)
         at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.RequestConnector(NpgsqlConnection connection)
         at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.OpenInternal(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
         at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
```

Below are the some project.json files and docker file which used in solution.

**Core project.json file**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Core Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Jignesh" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "Dapper": "1.50.0-beta8",
    "Dapper.Contrib": "1.50.0-beta8",
    "Npgsql": "3.1.0-alpha6",
    "System.Net.Security": "4.0.0-beta-*",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-beta-*"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": {}
  }
}
```

**Docker file**

```
FROM jignesh/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-update2-coreclr

RUN printf "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie main\n" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

# Add the PostgreSQL PGP key to verify their Debian packages.
# It should be the same key as https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8

# Add PostgreSQL's repository. It contains the most recent stable release
# of PostgreSQL, ``9.3``.
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

# Install ``python-software-properties``, ``software-properties-common`` and PostgreSQL 9.3
# There are some warnings (in red) that show up during the build. You can hide
# them by prefixing each apt-get statement with DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-software-properties software-properties-common postgresql-9.3 postgresql-client-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/src/WebAPI
RUN ["dnu", "restore"]

EXPOSE 5002/tcp

ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "-p", ".", "web"]
```

**Note** jignesh/aspnet is my local docker image file which I have created for 1.0.0-rc1-update2-coreclr as hub.docker.com doesn't have that.

**global.json**

```
{
  "projects": [
    "wrap",
    "src",
    "test"
  ],
  "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update2",
        "runtime": "coreclr",
        "architecture": "x64"
  }
}
```

Can someone help here ? What should I do to resolve this issue.

Let me know if more information is required.

**Additional Information**

**dnx version information in ubuntu**

```
Microsoft .NET Execution environment
 Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16609
 Type:         CoreClr
 Architecture: x64
 OS Name:      Linux
 OS Version:   ubuntu 14.04
 Runtime Id:   ubuntu.14.04-x64
```

**dnx version information in docker**

```
Microsoft .NET Execution environment
 Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16609
 Type:         CoreClr
 Architecture: x64
 OS Name:      Linux
 OS Version:   8 debian
 Runtime Id:   ubuntu.14.04-x64
```

Comment: I found this to be related to your issue: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4533

Comment: @zmechanic I already reviewed issue which you have mentioned. In my ubuntu machine it is working perfectly. I am facing issue only when I try to run in docker. There is one similar issue with redis package which I am facing with npgsql https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/350. This issue is still open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/350 I changed `RUN ["dnu", "restore"]` line to `RUN ["dnu", "restore","--runtime=ubuntu.14.04-x64"]` in dockerfile and issue gets resolved.

**Note** aspnet docker image already has line `ENV DNX_RUNTIME_ID ubuntu.14.04-x64` but don't know why this only is not sufficient and required to set runtime in `dnu restore`.

Anyway I am happy that adding runtime in `dnu restore` solved my problem.